# JUnit Tests - Is a call to JUnitCore.main() necessary?

Tags: java, ant, junit

Good afternoon,

I am running some JUnit tests on my application using ant. In doing so I am following the instructions in the step-by-step Spring-MVC tutorial. [*]

The instructions never mention a call to org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.main() in running a test. My question is, is it necessary to call org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.main to run a test if you are running the tests through command-line ant (as opposed to an IDE)? Or is ant smart enough to locate all the methods in a TestCase subclass and run all of them without an explicit call to JUnitCore.main()?

[*] http://static.springsource.org/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/part3.html

Thanks,
ktm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ant knows what to do. As long as you're using the right ant-task for that (like jUnit task: http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/junit.html).

Comment: So does it run every method in that class, in the order that it appears in the class? I ask this because the tutorial gives a method called setUp which initializes an object, which is the first method in the class. Following this is the method that performs the test. If I were to switch the order of the two methods, would it not work? I am about to figure this out for myself, but I'd just like to confirm that the order of methods is indeed significant.

Comment: well, the order in which the methods were declared is irrelevant, as long as they are called setUp and test***. If you use jUnit 4, you can just annotate the methods as @BeforeTest, @BeforeClass, @Test